# C++ move semantics and function call

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

I'm refreshing my C++ skills and relearning move semantics.
Here is the sample program and output which I can't make sense of.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int sepI = 0;
void printSep(const char* msg) {
    std::cout
        << std::setw(40) << std::setfill('>') << "" << std::setfill(' ')
        << std::setw(2) << std::setiosflags(std::ios::right) << sepI++ << ": " << std::resetiosflags(std::ios::right)
        << std::setiosflags(std::ios::left) << msg << std::resetiosflags(std::ios::left)
        << std::endl;
}

void printHook(const char* msg, void* p) {
    std::cout
        << std::setw(25) << std::setiosflags(std::ios::left) << msg << std::resetiosflags(std::ios::left)
        << std::setw(15) << std::setiosflags(std::ios::right) << p << std::resetiosflags(std::ios::right)
        << std::endl;
}

class MyT {
public:
    MyT() { printHook("constructor call", this); }
    MyT(MyT& t) { printHook("copy constructor call", this); }
    MyT(MyT&& t) { printHook("move constructor call", this); }

    ~MyT() { printHook("destructor call", this); v = 0; }

    MyT& operator=(MyT& t) { printHook("copy assigment call", this); return *this; }
    MyT& operator=(MyT&& t) { printHook("move assigment call", this); return *this; }

    int v = 1;
};

MyT fn() { return MyT(); }

int main() {
    printSep("a");
    MyT a;

    printSep("MyT&& v1 = std::move(a)");

    MyT&& v1 = std::move(a);
    std::cout << v1.v << " " << &v1 << std::endl;

    printSep("MyT&& v2 = MyT()");

    MyT&& v2 = MyT();
    std::cout << v2.v << " " << &v2 << std::endl;

    printSep("MyT&& v3 = std::move(MyT())");

    MyT&& v3 = std::move(MyT());
    std::cout << v3.v << " " << &v3 << std::endl;

    printSep("MyT&& v4 = fn()");

    MyT&& v4 = fn();
    std::cout << v4.v << " " << &v4 << std::endl;

    printSep("MyT&& v5 = std::move(fn())");

    MyT&& v5 = std::move(fn());
    std::cout << v5.v << " " << &v5 << std::endl;

    printSep("end");

    return 0;
}
```

```
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> 0: a                            OK.
constructor call          0x7ffe656eeae0
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> 1: MyT&& v1 = std::move(a)      OK. Makes sense.
1 0x7ffe656eeae0
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> 2: MyT&& v2 = MyT()             OK. Makes sense.
constructor call          0x7ffe656eeae8
1 0x7ffe656eeae8
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> 3: MyT&& v3 = std::move(MyT())  NOT OK.
constructor call          0x7ffe656eeaec
destructor call           0x7ffe656eeaec
1 0x7ffe656eeaec
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> 4: MyT&& v4 = fn()              NOT OK.
constructor call          0x7ffe656eeaf0
1 0x7ffe656eeaf0
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> 5: MyT&& v5 = std::move(fn())   NOT OK.
constructor call          0x7ffe656eeaf4
destructor call           0x7ffe656eeaf4
1 0x7ffe656eeaf4
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> 6: end
destructor call           0x7ffe656eeaf4
destructor call           0x7ffe656eeaf0
destructor call           0x7ffe656eeae8
destructor call           0x7ffe656eeae0
```

The questions are for the steps 3, 4, 5.

**3**
What's happening here?
Why isn't it the same as with step 2?
How is it possible that under the same address `0x7ffe656eeaec` we called `constructor - destructor - print` chain and didn't get segfault?\

**4 and 5**
Where was the memory allocated from?
How did we get 2 different addresses of  MyT instance out of non dynamic allocations in `fn()` calls?
Is it reserved static calls memory? Or they are allocated on stack then? Like compiler sees that those are local vars and reserves in program memory areas for such things. But I looked into disassembly and it was an ordinary function call. I couldn't check it on dynamic data, as I can't create rvalues array.\

It doesn't matter which optimization flags I set, as results are the same. But here is the build command:

```
g++ -std=c++17 -g -Wall -O3 -pedantic
```

**Update 1:** Reduced the code example.

Comment: I'd remove parts of the code unrelated to the question.

Comment: `and didn't get segfault?` because its called __undefined__ behavior for a reason.

Comment: This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think local variable cannot have different address? If you call it at different function, then they sure would (most-likely) be different.

Comment: The question doesn't really have anything to do with move-semantics by the way. If you replace `std::move` by a function that just returns its argument as a reference and replace all rvalue references with `const` lvalue references you are back in pre-C++11 before move semantics with the same behavior. It is about lifetime of temporary objects. See https://godbolt.org/z/4MsacE643.

Comment: Short answer, since the question has been closed now: Temporaries live until the end of the full-expression in which they are manifested, unless they are bound _immediately_,  not through a function call, to a reference, in which case their lifetime is extended until the end of the scope of the reference. (Immediately is not exactly correct, certain intervening expressions are allowed, but not function calls. References in function parameters won't reduce lifetime either, though.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3. It's undefined behavior. You pass a temporary object as an argument to the parameter of `std::move()`, the parameter is a local variable of `std::move()`. The function returns a reference to a local variable, a returned reference to a local variable does not prolong an object life. This is undefined behavior.

*The question was edited. The original question asked about the 10th case. Now this is 3.*

4. Is OK. `&&` prolongs life time of a temporary object.
5. Is the same issue 3.

Comment: Doesn't 3 and 5 equal to case 4? I mean, from the standpoint of vars lifetime, they all temporary. At 3 it's created and moved (but nowhere to move). At 4 it's created as local var of fn call, and supposed to be destructed, but still I was able to access it. At 5, the same as 4, it is still temporary. Why && doesn't prolong the lifetime for 3 and 5 then?

Comment: No, 4 is a completely different case. && with a temporary object is ok, && with a returned local variable is UB. `fn` does not create and return a local variable. Please show that local variable name. Local variable life can't be prolonged, because a local variable is located on a stack or a register. A reference can't refer to a destroyed local stack frame or a register.

Comment: Well it doesn't return variable, but it creates an local scoped object MyT and immediately returns it. These local scoped object is also created on stack, isn't it? What's the difference then? @user17732522 in the comments to the question wrote about immediate binding, which I'm not aware of. Is it what you also talking about?

Comment: Refresh you knowledge about RVO. In older compilers you would see copy constructor call and a non local copy would be referenced.

Comment: Immediate binding means binding with just a created object. Binding to a returned object is not an immediate binding. If a temporary is bound immediately, it's ok.